# How to add ToolTip to QSlider on mouse move

Tags: c++, qt, qslider, qtooltip

I want to have tooltip for QSlider showing the current value of slider on mouse move in QT C++

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code that can be discussed.

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring the lack of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of OP…

…here we go:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QSlider qSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
  qSlider.setRange(0, 100);
  qSlider.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qSlider, &QSlider::sliderMoved,
    [&](int value) {
#if 0 // not so nice -> delayed
      qSlider.setToolTip(QString("%1").arg(value));
#else // better
      QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), QString("%1").arg(value), nullptr);
#endif // 0
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of testQSliderToolTip (animated)]

The essential part of this MCVE is this:

```
  QObject::connect(&qSlider, &QSlider::sliderMoved,
    [&](int value) {
#if 0 // not so nice -> delayed
      qSlider.setToolTip(QString("%1").arg(value));
#else // better
      QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), QString("%1").arg(value), nullptr);
#endif // 0
    });
```

The `QSlider::sliderMoved()` signal is connected to a slot (provided as lambda) which sets the current value as tooltip.

For this, the `QSlider::setToolTip()` function (inherited from `QWidget`) could be used. When using this, I recognized an annoying delay (which I remember from my own projects how it can be fixed).

Using `QToolTip::showText()` instead, provides a better appearance.

Please, note that I preferred `QSlider::sliderMoved()` over `QSlider::valueChanged()`. The latter is called for any change of slider (even those not resulting from user interaction) while the former is specifically called

> when sliderDown is true and the slider moves. This usually happens when the user is dragging the slider.

---

Further reading:

- [QSlider::sliderMoved()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#sliderMoved)
- [QSlider::setToolTip()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop)
- [QToolTip::showText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText).